# Modify xpath expressions to get correct etree.getpath() result

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I have a lot of xpath expressions stored in database which are correct I belive. The problem I've faced is that without modifying them I can not get correct results when trying to get elements path usin lxml. Here is the python code:

```
def get_elements(response, xpath):

    # Scrapy SelectorList
    elements = response.xpath(xpath)

    if not elements:
        return []

    result = []
    tree = elements[0].root.getroottree()
    for element in elements:
        result.append(tree.getpath(element.root))

    return result
```

For example, this xpath expression

```
`//div[contains(@class, 'class')]//h3//a/@href`
```

works fine and I can get the value, but not the element path.

On this line

`tree = elements[0].root.getroottree()`

it raises an error

> str object has no attribute getroottree

If I remove the last `/@href` in expression it will get the element path.

For another expressions like

`//div[contains(@class, 'class')]//h3//a/@href|//div[contains(@class, 'another_class')]//h2//a/@href`

or

`//h3//a/text()|//strong[contains(@class, 'title')]//a/text()`

I need to remove all `/@href` and `/text()` to get the results.

For now, I modify the xpath like this to get correct elements:

```
element_path = "|".join(
        "/".join(r for r in s.split("/") if not (r.startswith('@') or r.endswith('()'))) for s in xpath.split("|")
    )
```

But there are a lot of expressions in database like

`.//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' bref_list ')]//a/@href`

that will be incorrect after modifying

`.//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(.//h2[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(.//a`

and raising Invalid Xpath error, or like this

`.//article[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' post-11508 ')]//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' posted-on ')] | .//article[(contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' post ') and (position() >= 3) and (((position() - 3) mod 1) = 0))]//time[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' entry-date ')]/text()`

So, is there any basic rules or something like that which I could use or how should I modify xpath expressions to make them work?

PS: I couldn't modify expressions in database directly.

Comment: It sounds like getPath() only works on element nodes, and fails when you return an attribute or text node. Perhaps your library has some other way to get from an attribute or text node to its parent element. But I don't know the library you are using.

Comment: The `root` attribute of a Selector bound to an attribute is a string object. Test with `scrapy.Selector(text="<a test='success'/>").xpath("//@test")[0].root`